# path definition not recognized in ant

Tags: ant

I defined a path in a file called unittest.xml in the following way(line 26):

```
 <path id="tasks.path">
        <pathelement location="${publish.home}/INSIDE/UnitTest/testinganttasks.jar"/>
    </path>
```

next I tried to use the path  in the following way:

```
   <classpath>
        <path refid="tasks.path" />
     </classpath>
```

in a taskdef tag.
when I run my ant code, it does everything well until I get the following error:

> BUILD FAILED unittest.xml:296: The
>   following error occurred while
>   executing this line: unittest.xml:281:
>   Reference tasks.path not found.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: we will need to see the lines as we don't have access to your build script

Answer (score 0):

You should see this example at http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#references

```
<project ... >
  <path id="project.class.path">
    <pathelement location="lib/"/>
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}/"/>
    <pathelement path="${additional.path}"/>
  </path>

  <target ... >
    <rmic ...>
      <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
    </rmic>
  </target>

  <target ... >
    <javac ...>
      <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
    </javac>
  </target>
</project>
```

I think your problem is that in classpath you should not nest path element, but give id of the path for the classpath element itself.